# How to make a button in a list active in Ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

**"detail"** in ***ngFor** is coming from the **server** and is it is containing a **list**.
 and I am selecting a **item** from it. I want to to make that **button active** when 
 the user clicks it and it should remain **active** until the user **selects another 
 option** from the list. I am using **[ngClass]** but it is activating a button for **1 to 2** seconds.

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item [ngClass]="configop.selection" *ngFor="let configop of detail" (click)="itemSelected(configop)" >
        <div class="ion-item optionalItem">
            <div class="ion-button">
                <span class="color-code" >
                    <img src="{{configop.image}}">
                    </span>
                    <span class="color-name">{{ configop.name }}</span>
                <span class="color-price">{{ configop.price|currency:'PKR':false }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</ion-list>

.ts file
    itemSelected(configop: any) {
      if(this.selection !=null){
        if(configop.name == this.selection){
          this.storage.remove('carPaint');
          this.selection=configop.name;
        }
        else {
          this.storage.remove('carPaint');
          this.storage.set('carPaint', configop);
          this.selection=configop.name;}
        }
        else {
          this.storage.set('carPaint', configop);
          this.selection=configop.name;}
        }
```

Comment: is button will be disabled intially

Comment: Button should not be disabled.

I want that :
When a user selects a item from the list then that button should be active until or unless the user deselects that item or selects another item from the list @ArunKumaresh

Answer (score 5):

Make a unique id to each button and assign the unique id to another variable and css class based on the selected id

```
<button (click)="active(1)" [ngClass]="{'activeclass': activebutton === 1 }" type="button">button1</button>
<button (click)="active(2)" [ngClass]="{'activeclass': activebutton === 2 }" type="button">button2</button>
```

Make a function to add the css class to the selected button

```
 public activebutton: number;
    active(buttonvalue: number) {
        if (this.activebutton === buttonvalue) {
          this.activebutton= 0;
        }
        else {
          this.activebutton= buttonvalue;
        }
      }
```

Comment: i am using single button not multiple buttons

Comment: one button if we select one item it will be get activated can you explain clearly what you needed. you said single button then why  <button ion-item [ngClass]="configop.selection" *ngFor="let configop of detail" (click)="itemSelected(configop)" > when you loop through the button it will create multiple buttons

Comment: yes your answer is right in some scenario but not in my case

Comment: `[ngClass]="{'deactivated': selection != configop.name ,'activated': selection == null}"`

this line solved my problem

Comment: is my answer is useful if it mark my answer as right